# ROS kinetic Kame on Ubuntu17.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is ROS kinetic Kame cannot be installed on Ubuntu 17.04?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260219/ros-kinetic-kame-on-ubuntu17.04/) by [Harry Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/30151/harry-lau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No it cannot

---

Originally posted by [Harry Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/30151/harry-lau/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0